# C program to delete all unnecessary blanks from a string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I tried to make a C function which deletes all unnecessary spaces from a string. For an example:

```
    Hi       my      name is  Leon   .
```

After function call, it should look like following:
`Hi my name is Leon.`
But my program always lefts one blank space after the last word, so it looks like this:

```
Hi my name is Leon .
```

Any ideas for how can that be fixed?
Here's the code:

```
char *DeleteSpaces(char *str) {
int blank = 1;
char *poc, *start = str, *q;
q = str;
while (*q == ' ') q++;
    poc = str;
    while (*poc++ = *q++);
while (*str != '\0') {
    q = str;
    if (*str == ' ') {
        if ((blank >= 1 && *(str-1) == ' ')) {
            poc = str;
            while (*poc == ' ') {
                poc++;
            }
            q = str;
            while(*poc != '\0') {
                *q++ = *poc++;
            }
            *q = '\0';
            blank = 0;

        }
        blank++;
    }
    else if (blank == 1)
        blank = 0;
    str++;
}
str--;
if (str == ' ') *str = '\0';

return start;
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Crashes at runtime? Unexpected results? Please elaborate. Also, how do you call this function? What do you pass as argument? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I get unexpected results, as i mentioned above. I also gave an example

Comment: You compact a series of spaces into a single one. You'll need to add logic if you want to remove spaces completely before a `.`.

Comment: If i understand right, you have to include non literal characters (or just punctuations) in your check and keep them, thus , seeing 5 spaces and comma, you keep the comma, etc

Comment: Please do some research what comments are for. Hint: your code is hard to understand, not only due to formatting, but also missing explanations.

Comment: You're not taking punctuation into account; you'll need some additional logic to remove *all* spaces between a letter and a period (or comma, or semicolon, or question mark, etc.).  Also, your code seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) variable names should be meaningful.  I.E. indicate usage or contents (or better, both).  'poc' and 'q' are meaningless, even in the current context.  3) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 4) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'  unindent before every closing brace '}. suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: when posting a 'why does my code not work' question, please post code that cleanly compiles and runs,  I.E. include a `main()` function that calls the function that contains the problem.  include the `#include` statements needed so the code can be compiled.

Comment: What output should you get from: `[  He said, "Don't do it!"   ]` (where you can treat the `[]` as marking the ends of the string).  Should the space be preserved between the comma and the double quote?  What's the algorithm for that?  Suppose there are spaces around the `!` and close double quote (`[   !   "   ]`); what should be the output.  Your code successfully eliminates leading spaces and reduces sequences of one or more spaces to one space.  Maybe dealing with punctuation spacing is a separate job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of subtle issues to consider in removing *whitespace* from a string in place. One significant issue is preserving a pointer to the *beginning* of the original so if the original is *dynamically allocated*, you do not lose the ability to `free` the memory later, thereby causing a memory leak.

Secondly, you have three basic reindexing considerations: (1) leading whitespace; (2) interleaved whitespace; and (3) whitespace after the end. (plus any custom cases you want to build in like trimming any whitespace before a `'.'`). You can pretty much take them in order in your routine.

While you are simply looking at a `' '` (`space`) character now, there is no reason you shouldn't also handle all *whitespace* the same. The `ctype.h` header provides the `isspace` function (macro) to do just that.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following to `rmxws` (*remove excess whitespace*):

```
char *rmxws (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;             /* valdiate string not NULL */
    if (!*s) return s;                    /* handle empty string */

    char *p = s, *wp = s;            /* pointer and write-pointer */

    while (*p) {
        if (isspace(*p)) {                         /* test for ws */
            if (wp > s)               /* ignore leading ws, while */
                *wp++ = *p;         /* preserving 1 between words */
            while (*p && isspace (*p))         /* skip remainder  */
                p++;
            if (!*p)                     /* bail on end-of-string */
                break;
        }
        if (*p == '.')       /* handle space between word and '.' */
            while (wp > s && isspace (*(wp - 1)))
                wp--;
        *wp++ = *p;                            /* use non-ws char */
        p++;
    }
    while (wp > s && isspace (*(wp - 1)))     /* trim trailing ws */
        wp--;
    *wp = 0;    /* nul-terminate */

    return s;
}
```

Putting that together with a short example, you could test as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *rmxws (char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : (char []){ " Testing  1 2  3. . .  "};
    printf ("\n original : '%s'\n", s);
    printf (" trimmed  : '%s'\n\n", rmxws (s));

    return 0;
}

char *rmxws (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;             /* valdiate string not NULL */
    if (!*s) return s;                    /* handle empty string */

    char *p = s, *wp = s;            /* pointer and write-pointer */

    while (*p) {
        if (isspace(*p)) {                         /* test for ws */
            if (wp > s)               /* ignore leading ws, while */
                *wp++ = *p;         /* preserving 1 between words */
            while (*p && isspace (*p))         /* skip remainder  */
                p++;
            if (!*p)                     /* bail on end-of-string */
                break;
        }
        if (*p == '.')       /* handle space between word and '.' */
            while (wp > s && isspace (*(wp - 1)))
                wp--;
        *wp++ = *p;                            /* use non-ws char */
        p++;
    }
    while (wp > s && isspace (*(wp - 1)))     /* trim trailing ws */
        wp--;
    *wp = 0;    /* nul-terminate */

    return s;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trimxsws "    Hi       my      name is  Leon   .  "

 original : '    Hi       my      name is  Leon   .  '
 trimmed  : 'Hi my name is Leon.'
```

or just

```
$ ./bin/trimxsws

 original : ' Testing  1 2  3. . .  '
 trimmed  : 'Testing 1 2 3...'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Hey David. I feel like If I understand this then I understand pointer. However I don't. In the while(*p) loop. I can  write an printf wp and printf p function. But I can know in which way the space is trimmed. I understand  There is pointer loop through string. I just don't know how you delete the white space....

Comment: @jian Hah, this is a fun use of pointers. `p` is just the current pointer you are iterating down the string, `wp` is the write-pointer that you will only increment when when you (1) encounter the first non-whitespace with `p`, or (2) on the first whitespace between words, or (3) you use it to backup from the end overwriting trailing whitespace. You are just ignoring leading whitespace, compressing multiple spaces between words to one space, and then backing up from the end ignoring whatespace until you read the last non-whitespace character (and then nul-terminating at `wp` at the end.

Comment: Easy way to is to take `" a  b. "` and just work through the loops with your pencil and paper handy and each character of the original drawn inside a box, e.g. `" |a| | |b|.| |"` and then put a little `p` and `wp` under the current cell (memory address) where each pointer is). Remember `wp` is the address and `*wp` is the character at that address, and the short examples really help cement things (rather than bogging down in the tedium of a long example). I'd probably write this slightly different today -- but makes no difference for the learning value (or performance for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a space is needed to be saved in `dest` only when a non-space character follows a non-leading space.  Simplifies the loop.

```
char *DeleteSpaces(char *str) {
  char *start = str;
  char *dest = str;

  // skip leading spaces
  while (*str == ' ') str++;

  char previous = 0;
  char ch;

  while ((ch = *str++) != '\0') {
    if (ch != ' ') {
      if (previous == ' ') {
        *dest++ = previous;
      }
      *dest++ = ch;
    }
    previous = ch;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
  return start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code

1. seems to work, I have not rigorously tested it.
2. cleanly compiles
3. returns the original pointer to the char string
4. performs the function, inplace

and now the code

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *DeleteSpaces(char *str) 
{
    char * src = str;
    char * dest = str;

    int inBlank = 0;

    while( *src )
    {
        if ( isalpha( *src ) )
        {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;
            inBlank = 0;
        }

        else if( ispunct(*src) )
        {
            if( inBlank )
            {
                dest--;
            }

            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;
            inBlank = 0; 
        }

        else if( isspace( *src ) )
        {
            if( inBlank )
            {
                src++;
            }

            else
            {
                inBlank =1;
                *dest = *src;
                dest++;
                src++;  
            }           
        }
    }

    *dest = '\0';

    return str;
}
```